# is there a way to detect what type of image is being loaded from an img src that is redirected?

Tags: javascript, facebook, mime-types

I'm using the this facebook service to return profile pictures.

`<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/username/picture">`

If the fb user did not set a profile picture, the service redirects to this facebook anonymous person image: `http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yo/r/UlIqmHJn-SK.gif`.  I would like to avoid presenting those.

Is there a way, using javascript, to detect if the image returned is `http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yo/r/UlIqmHJn-SK.gif`.  That address is from a CDN, so I wonder if we can just check the file size is <= 390B and mime-type is image/gif?

EDIT: Unfortunately the solutions involving only modern browsers (HTML5 and canvas) might not work for me since the requirement is that we still need to support back to ie7.

Comment: Could you give an example of a URL pointing to a user's picture?

Comment: I took 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript

and

http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/

and came up with 

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/NRsh4/

but it does not handle gif :(((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, you can simply make your request with AJAX and parse the MIME-type yourself. Indeed, Facebook includes this header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This authorizes [CORS](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) (Cross Origin Resource Sharing), which is now supported by most browsers.

If you absolutely must support old browsers, have a look at the Open Graph documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/using-pictures/

Instead of directly fetching the picture, you can just fetch its metadata with JSONP. This should work in IE7:

```
function checkPictureUrl(userName, cb) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + userName + '/picture?redirect=false',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (json) {
      // user only has a default profile picture
      if(json.data.is_silhouette)
        return cb(null);
      else
        return cb(null, json.data.url);
    },
    error: function (err) {
      cb(err);
    }
  });
}
```